# How to return multiple ref cursor from PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I have successfully created a function. I want to return multiple ref cursors like below. When I execute the function I get a response like in the image below. How can I solve this problem?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.get_dashboard_graph(
    p_fromdate character varying,
    p_todate character varying)
    RETURNS SETOF refcursor 
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100.0
    VOLATILE 
    ROWS 1000.0
AS $function$

DECLARE
      process_wise_positrol refcursor;           
      process_wise_micro_audit refcursor;
      process_wise_positrol_line_stop refcursor;          
      process_wise_micro_audit_line_stop refcursor;
BEGIN

-- process wise positrol completed
OPEN process_wise_positrol FOR
    select count(*), d.dd_value from audit_transaction t, audit_master m, dd_type_details d 
    where t.audit_id = m.audit_id and m.activity_id = 9 and t.iscompleted = 'completed' and d.dd_id = m.process 
    and audit_start_time BETWEEN p_fromdate::timestamp AND p_todate::timestamp group by d.dd_value;
RETURN NEXT process_wise_positrol;

-- process wise Micro audit completed
OPEN process_wise_micro_audit FOR
    select count(*), d.dd_value from audit_transaction t, audit_master m, dd_type_details d 
    where t.audit_id = m.audit_id and m.activity_id = 8 and t.iscompleted = 'completed' 
    and d.dd_id = m.process 
    and audit_start_time BETWEEN p_fromdate::timestamp AND p_todate::timestamp group by d.dd_value;
RETURN NEXT process_wise_micro_audit;

-- process wise positrol line stop
OPEN process_wise_positrol_line_stop FOR
    select count(*), d.dd_value from audit_transaction t
    left join audit_master m on m.audit_id= t.audit_id
    left join dd_type_details d on d.dd_id= m.process
    left join audit_ques_link al on al.audit_trans_id= t.audit_trans_id
    where t.audit_id = m.audit_id and m.activity_id = 9 and al.line_stop = 0
    and t.iscompleted = 'completed' and d.dd_id = m.process 
    and audit_start_time BETWEEN p_fromdate::timestamp AND p_todate::timestamp 
    group by d.dd_value;
RETURN NEXT process_wise_positrol_line_stop;

-- process wise Micro audit line  stop
OPEN process_wise_micro_audit_line_stop FOR
    select count(*), d.dd_value from audit_transaction t
    left join audit_master m on m.audit_id= t.audit_id
    left join dd_type_details d on d.dd_id= m.process
    left join audit_ques_link al on al.audit_trans_id= t.audit_trans_id
    where t.audit_id = m.audit_id and m.activity_id = 8 and al.line_stop = 0
    and t.iscompleted = 'completed' and d.dd_id = m.process 
    and audit_start_time BETWEEN p_fromdate::timestamp AND p_todate::timestamp 
    group by d.dd_value;
RETURN NEXT process_wise_micro_audit_line_stop;

END;

$function$;

ALTER FUNCTION public.get_dashboard_graph(character varying, character varying)
    OWNER TO postgres;
```

When I execute above function It returns output like below.

```
select * from get_Dashboard_Graph('09/01/2018','09/28/2018');
```

[image]

Comment: I think this is  a limitation of pgAdmin. There is nothing you can do in your code

Comment: My above problem was solved now I am struggling  that how can I call this function with MVC C# ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got exactly what you wanted – four cursors.

After cou have called the function, you can run the SQL statement

```
FETCH NEXT FROM "<unnamed portal 26>";
```

If you don't like the name of the cursor, assign a different one inside the function body:

```
process_wise_micro_audit := 'auditcursor';
```

Then you can call `FETCH` like this after the function has finished:

```
FETCH NEXT FROM auditcursor;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have tried and successfully got response what i want but every time when I execute my above function it change count of "unnamed portal". How can fix this ?

Comment: As I said, assign a name to the `refcursor` variable in the function.

Comment: OK Thanks . Should i also write "FETCH NEXT FROM "<unnamed portal 26>";" in  function ?

Comment: No; that is run *after* the function was called. I'll edit the answer to make this clearer.

Comment: Thanks @Laurenz Albe. I think this very bad with postgresql that if I have n number of refcurser then I have to write FETCH statement for each cursor.

Comment: Well, you could automatize it. You get the names as result of the function, so you can loop.